# Callback from other thread

Tags: c++, dll, callback

I have problem with callbacks from other application thread. Dll is some kind of wrapper between Addinational application and Application program and its working within Application program memory(with same PID). Addinational application(other thread and PID) is application which in main loop looking for "something" and when found it, it calls Callback function from Dll and then Dll calls Callback function from Application program. Maybe its little confusing look at image above.
And theres crash(when dll calls callback function from application program) with message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x70786a46 in MainProgram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000164.
>
> Call stack mshtml.dll

Propably application program using IE controls to update UI. How could I update UI when Addinational application callsback?

[image: Callbacks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendMessage` is a general solution for posting results to a GUI thread. It does all thread synchronization for you and doesn’t return until the message has been processed by the receiver thread's window.

`PostThreadMessage` is less reliable since the message may/will be lost when the receiver is in a modal loop for e.g. `MessageBox`, unless you have added a hook that intercepts the thread message – so just use `SendMessage`.

More advanced techniques involve doing the thread synchronization yourself, e.g. with a buffer, but anyway that will probably also involve `SendMessage` for a GUI thread, so, I suggest you just start with that, and if that’s good enough, then don’t do more.

**EDIT**: dang, I see now that although the first sentence talks about threads, it's really about sending data from one process to another process. Well, for that there is [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Please consider that a (user level) pointer from one process, *is not valid in the other process*.

Comment: Yes that is a possibility. However check out UIPI if the application should run on Vista or later.

Comment: @user877329 thanks. but we're talking thread synchronization here. User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) is not an issue for that. And so `SendMessage` works nicely up to and including Windows 7.

Comment: I've tried this, PostMessage crashes application(Same error as earlier), SendMessage stops on UI update function and breaks function(not application). I'm creating hidden window to handle messages through hwnd = CreateWindow(args), starting message loop in addinational thread, adding Proc function and then SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APP + 101, 0,0); - anyway doesnt update UI :/

Comment: Is `LRESULT CALLBACK DLLWindowProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` performed in main thread or in addinational application thread if I sendmessage from addinational application thread ?

Comment: @user1112008: That's explained by the `SendMessage` documentation. If you do not have a full Visual Studio installation with local help viewer, then simply google "`SendMessage`". Among the results, choose Microsoft's documentation. Check out the "Remarks" section.

Comment: _Please consider that a (user level) pointer from one process, is not valid in the other process._

I'm looking for a way to do this. Addinational process callbacks function from Dll and that function fills structure which should be passed by pointer to Main application function(where update UI is).
[Pseudo-code](http://pastebin.com/aeaxrYz0)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to call a function that belongs to another process. I think you need to read about RPC:s http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx